# outputting a mysql distinct query only outputting the information i want

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create sort of a chat/pm system and I have some trouble with a specific query I would like to make

I have a table named messages with the following fields

ID, From_user_id, To_user_id, Content

When going to the inbox I want to show all users I have corresponded with but uniquely. So for instance I have the following content in my database

```
ID, From_user_id, To_user_id, Content
1,  1,            2,          hi
2,  1,            2,          hello
3,  2,            1,          hi
4,  1,            3,          hi
5,  3,            1,          hi
```

In the inbox of user1 I want to echo user_id 2 and user_id 3 
In the inbox of user2 I want to echo user_id 1
in the inbox of user3 I want to echo user_id 1

I tried the following code

```
$qinbox = "SELECT DISTINCT from_users_id, to_users_id from messages
WHERE from_users_id = $id OR to_users_id = $id";

$queryinbox = $db->query($qinbox);

while ($inbox = $queryinbox->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo $inbox['from_users_id']; 
            echo $inbox['to_users_id']; echo ' <p>' ; }
```

But then user1 gets the following rows

```
ID, From_user_id, To_user_id 
1,  1,            2              
3,  2,            1          
4,  1,            3          
5,  3,            1
```

while I want the result to be unique. It doesn't matter who it is. So from or to doesnt matter.

like a facebook or linkedin chat. So if I am user1 in this instance I want to see user2 and user3 and only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without **UNION**, so the faster

```
SELECT DISTINCT IF(from_users_id = $id, to_users_id, from_users_id) as user_id
FROM messages
WHERE from_users_id = $id OR to_users_id = $id;
```

Comment: Without the UNION is not necessarily faster; OR conditions tend to result in ignored indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it I think

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.user_id
FROM (SELECT from_users_id as user_id 
      FROM messages WHERE to_users_id = $id 
      UNION SELECT to_users_id 
      FROM messages WHERE from_users_id = $id) as a
```

Comment: thx for ur reply relativephpnewbie but where does a.user_id stand for. (I get an empty query)

Comment: The`a.` is the alias of the subquery as defined by `as a` after the closing bracket, `user_id` is the alias assigned to the column we select in the sub query. Kirill Stadler's answer should work also.

Comment: Are your column names correct, in the table definition you state `from_user_id` in your code you reference `from_users_id`